# NativeScript & SocketIO: Can't find variable: SocketManager

Tags: socket.io, nativescript, backendless

I'm trying to integrate Backendless [JS-SDK](https://github.com/Backendless/JS-SDK) into the NativeScript application.
The JS-SDK is dependent on [socket.io.client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) module which is not supported in the NS environment.

So, the first problem with the socket.io.client module I've solved by adding an alias in the custom webpack.json

```
const webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config");

module.exports = (env) => {
    env = env || {};

    env.alias = Object.assign({}, env.alias, {
        'socket.io-client': 'nativescript-socketio'
    });

    return webpackConfig(env);
}
```

but after that, I started receiving another error: `Object is not a function (near '...io...')`
and I tried to change initializing SocketIO instance as it described here [nativescript-socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-socket.io)
and now I get another error: `Can't find variable: SocketManager`, after some investigation I found the code line where the error comes from, ``:

[socketio.ios.js#130](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRka0.png)

Has anybody got this error?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Sounds like your native libraries are installed properly, generally a clean build should solve it.